# Column defined as auto-increment required on insert

Tags: ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to define a MS Access table through their SQL DDL. I have plenty of experience with traditional SQL, but the access specific language is throwing me for a loop.

```
CREATE TABLE DemoTable (
    Demo_id IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Demo_nm VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);
=> Query executed successfully. 0 rows were affected.
```

I've tried `AUTOINCREMENT`, `COUNTER` and `IDENTITY(1,1)` etc.

```
INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES('Some Name');
=> Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.
```

This is because it expects a Demo_id value.

```
INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES(5, 'Some Name');
=> Query executed successfully. 1 rows were affected.
```

Everything else is created correctly.. an index is created for the `Demo_id` and `Demo_nm` is not nullable.

My reference:

[How to: Modify a Table's Design Using Access SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE DemoTable (
    Demo_id Counter PRIMARY KEY,
    Demo_nm VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO DemoTable (   
Demo_nm ) Values ("abc")
```

Comment: Aghhh, but of course. Not sure how that slipped my mind! Thanks a bunch.